# Golang Multi templates caching

Tags: go

I'm new to the world of Golang and I'm trying to set up a web project with templates files and good caching system.

I have `layout.html`, `1.html`, `2.html`.

So I load `layout.html` in my render function :

```
err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout.html", nil)
```

`layout.html` look like this :

```
...   
<body>{{template "content" .}}</body>
...
```

`1.html`

```
{{define "content"}}This is the first page.{{end}}
```

`2.html`

```
{{define "content"}}This is the second page.{{end}}
```

I can't use

```
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    "layout.html",
    "1.html",
    "2.html"))
```

Because `2.html` override `1.html`.

So I have two ways :

1. Define ParseFiles in each handler function. (every time a page is rendered) Very bad perf
2. Define an array of template like this in the init function ([example](https://github.com/vitorsvieira/go-gorilla-boilerplate/blob/master/server.go)):

   `templates["1"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html","1.html"))
   templates["2"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html","2.html"))`

Is there any new way or better way to do this ?

Comment: Parsed templates don't "override" each other unless they have the same exact filename (but different path). They are all stored separately and you just exec it with the filename.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, can you show me an example pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package-level maps or variables are both a good way to cache compiled templates.  Code in #2 above is OK.  Here's how to use package-level variables:

```
var t1 = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html","1.html"))
var t2 = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html","2.html"))
```

Use the variables like this:

```
err := t1.Execute(w, data)
```

The code in the question and this code above in this answer load "layout.html" twice. This can be avoided:

```
var layout = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("layout.html"))
var t1 = template.Must(layout.Clone().ParseFiles("1.html"))
var t2 = template.Must(layout.Clone().ParseFiles("2.html"))
```

Comment: Thk, its OK, but I don t want to define a new variable or index on array for  each new page. No other way to render dynamically ?

Answer (score 3):

In my projects I use this helper function:

```
func executeTemplate(tmpls *template.Template, tmplName string, w io.Writer, data interface{}) error {
    var err error
    layout := tmpls.Lookup("layout.html")
    if layout == nil {
        return errNoLayout
    }

    layout, err = layout.Clone()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t := tmpls.Lookup(tmplName)
    if t == nil {
        return errNoTemplate
    }

    _, err = layout.AddParseTree("content", t.Tree)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return layout.Execute(w, data)
}
```

`tmpls` is the template which contains all parsed templates as "sub-templates", e.g. from `ParseFiles`. `layout.html` looks something like this:

```
<main class="container">
{{template "content" .}}
</main>
```

While other templates are like this:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Notice, content templates don't need to start with `{{define "content"}}`.